# Android adding fragments at runtime causes flicker

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-webview

I have a main activity with content - a WebView.

Basically, when the user opens the application, I do a quick check if they are logged in. If they aren't logged in, then I inflate the login fragment.

At this point, you get a flicker of the WebView underneath before the fragment is inflated.  It's a little bit clunky.  It has made other things worse by the fact that I have to hide/show the actionbar in the same step.

Is there any solution to get around this?  I guess I can hide my WebView until needed, but the actionbar will still be shown for a moment.  Any suggestions for this problem?